# MySQL not using indexes when joining against another table

Tags: mysql, performance, index, join, order-by

I have two tables, the first table contains all articles / blog posts within a CMS. Some of these articles may also appear in a magazine, in which case they have a foreign key relationship with another table that contains magazine specific information.

Here is a simplified version of the create table syntax for these two tables with some non-essential rows stripped out:

```
CREATE TABLE `base_article` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_published` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `content` longtext,
  `is_published` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `base_article_date_published` (`date_published`),
  KEY `base_article_is_published` (`is_published`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `mag_article` (
    `basearticle_ptr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `issue_slug` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
    `rubric` varchar(75) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`basearticle_ptr_id`),
    KEY `mag_article_issue_slug` (`issue_slug`),
    CONSTRAINT `basearticle_ptr_id_refs_id` FOREIGN KEY (`basearticle_ptr_id`) REFERENCES `base_article` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The CMS contains around 250,000 articles total and I have written a simple [Python script](https://gist.github.com/joshmaker/6756596) that can be used to populate a test database with sample data if they want to replicate this issue locally.

If I select from one of these tables, MySQL has no problem picking an appropriate index or retrieving articles quickly. However, when the two tables are joined together in a simple query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `base_article` 
INNER JOIN `mag_article` ON (`mag_article`.`basearticle_ptr_id` = `base_article`.`id`)
WHERE is_published = 1
ORDER BY `base_article`.`date_published` DESC
LIMIT 30
```

MySQL fails to pick an appropriate index and performance plummets. Here is the relevant explain extended (the execution time for which is over a second):

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table     |  type  |           possible_keys           |   key   | key_len |                  ref                   | rows  | filtered |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mag_article  | ALL    | PRIMARY                           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                   | 23830 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | base_article | eq_ref | PRIMARY,base_article_is_published | PRIMARY | 4       | my_test.mag_article.basearticle_ptr_id |     1 | 100.00   | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

- EDIT SEPT 30: I can remove the `WHERE` clause from this query, but the `EXPLAIN` still looks the same and the query is still slow.

One potential solution is to force an index. Running the same query with `FORCE INDEX (base_articel_date_published)` results in a query that executes in around 1.6 milliseconds.

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------+-------------+
| id | select_type |    table     |  type  | possible_keys |             key             | key_len |           ref           | rows | filtered  |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | base_article | index  | NULL          | base_article_date_published |       9 | NULL                    |   30 | 833396.69 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mag_article  | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY                     |       4 | my_test.base_article.id |    1 | 100.00    |             |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------+-------------+
```

I would prefer not to have to force an index on this query if I can avoid it, for several reasons. Most notably, this basic query can be filtered / modified in a variety of ways (such as filtering by the `issue_slug`) after which `base_article_date_published` may no longer be the best index to use.

Can anyone suggest a strategy for improving performance for this query?

Comment: if column "is_published" only keeps two or three values you could really drop that index KEY `base_article_is_published` (`is_published`).. looks to me it's an boolean type..

Comment: edited the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this this should remove the need for an "Using temporary; Using filesort" because the data is in the right sort already.

You need to know the trick why MySQL needs "Using temporary; Using filesort"  to remove that need.

**See second sqlfriddle for an explain about removing the need**

```
SELECT
      *
    FROM base_article

    STRAIGHT_JOIN 
      mag_article
    ON
      (mag_article.basearticle_ptr_id = base_article.id)

    WHERE
      base_article.is_published = 1

    ORDER BY
      base_article.date_published DESC
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/302710/2

Works pretty good i needed this also some time ago for Country / city tables 
see demo here with example data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b34870/41

**Edited you also may want to analyse this answer if base_article.is_published = 1 always returns 1 record like your explain explained an INNER JOIN deliverd table may give better performance like the queries in the answer below**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738483/mysql-slow-query-using-filesort/18774937#18774937

Comment: Life saving answer! I was using `JOIN` only but MySQL was not picking up index. Thanks so much Raymond

Answer (score 4):

## REFACTOR THE QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM base_article
WHERE is_published = 1
ORDER BY date_published LIMIT 30) A
INNER JOIN mag_article B
ON A.id = B.basearticle_ptr_id;
```

or

```
SELECT B.*,C.* FROM
(SELECT id FROM base_article
WHERE is_published = 1
ORDER BY date_published LIMIT 30) A
LEFT JOIN base_article ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN mag_article C ON B.id = C.basearticle_ptr_id;
```

## MODIFY YOUR INDEXES

```
ALTER TABLE base_article DROP INDEX base_article_is_published;
ALTER TABLE base_article ADD INDEX ispub_datepub_index (is_published,date_published);
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Refactor: Doesn't work I'm afraid, because the `LIMIT 30` is in the subquery (not all of those 30 rows will also be in the `mag_articles` table). If I move the `LIMIT` to the outer query the performance is the same as in my original. Modify Indexes: MySQL doesn't use that index either. Removing the `WHERE` clause from my original query doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The second refactor method worked incredibly good, the query time has been reduced dramatically from 8 seconds to 0.3 seconds in my table... thank you Sir!!