# LEFT JOIN statement is optimized on Mysql 5.5 but not 5.7, is this a bug?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.7

The following query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT usr.*,act.*,cht.*
FROM users AS usr
LEFT JOIN active_u AS act USING (uid)
LEFT JOIN chat AS cht USING(uid)
ORDER BY usr.updated DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

shows this on MySQL **5.5.58** (Unix):

[image: mysql]

and this on MySQL **5.7.17** (Windows):

[image: mysql]

How comes that Mysql 5.5 optimizes the query perfectly, **while 5.7 makes its best to slow down the query as much as possible?** It simply scans all the rows , uses temporary tables, etc. Is there some mysql variable that specifies that queries must not be optimized, or something?

I can assure that the 5.5 Unix installation is using all default values.

I know I could [refactor the query as shown here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50727/mysql-not-using-indexes-when-joining-against-another-table?newreg=231bda92b8014756a0af2086523e057b) to optimize it for 5.7, but how comes the query was already optimized perfectly on Mysql 5.5?

Also: Why, and this happens often, the **possible_keys** field shows `NULL` but it actually ends up using a key, like the `updated` key in the 5.5 screenshot?

Comment: Are the table definitions identical? Are all indexes identical between the two databases?

Comment: Do both versions have `INDEX(updated)`?  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` on 5.7.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes all indexes are identical and tables are practically the same, only the number of rows changes between versions.

Comment: @andreszs - I think the JSON will have the clue; can you provide it, at least for 5.7?